# Cannot query containerised SQL Server database from Azure DevOps Pipeline integration test

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an integration test that starts a Linux-based Docker container with SQL Server and a restored database. The test runs a simple `select count(*)` query and passes every time when running locally. When the test runs as part of an Azure DevOps Pipeline the test fails with the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "A" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.
  Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
```

When I change the test to query the `master` database instead of our own database, the query runs successfully and the test passes.

The core of the test is as follows:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
{
   await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

   using (var command = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [table];", connection))
   {
      var rowCount = (int)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
          
      rowCount.Should().BeGreaterThan(0);
   }
       
   connection.Close();
}
```

This connection string works:

```
var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "localhost,32808",
    UserID = "sa",
    Password = "P@ssword!23",
    InitialCatalog = "master",
    ConnectTimeout = 120,
    ConnectRetryCount = 3 
};
```

This one fails:

```
var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "localhost,32808",
    UserID = "sa",
    Password = "P@ssword!23",
    InitialCatalog = "A",
    ConnectTimeout = 120,
    ConnectRetryCount = 3 
};
```

Initially, the test was failing with a connection timeout. I added a longer timeout and the exception changed to this one. There's nothing obvious missing from the security settings: `sa` is the `dbo` of the `A` database. Also, the test passes locally using the same Docker image.

Any ideas about how to solve this, or get additional feedback via logging, etc. are gratefully received.

SQL Server 15.0.4023.6; Ubuntu 18.04.4; full Azure build agent specs [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu18/20200621.1/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md);

Comment: Since the test succeeds accessing a user object in the master database, it seems the objects were deployed to master instead of user database A. The login failed error would indicate the A database does not exist.

Comment: Why would this be different in the context of the DevOps build agent? It's the same Docker image as the one I use locally, and that has the database available.

Comment: Also, I can use the `master` connection string in the test and run this query successfully: `use [A]; select count(*) from ATable;` So, the A database must be there and is queryable.

Comment: Since the `USE A` succeeds, the db is obviously there when that query ran. My suspicion is that isn't yet available when the direct connection is made. There should be a related message in the SQL Server errorlog that details the reason for the login failure.

Comment: I think you're correct. I've added a 2 minute pause in the test and it now passes. The container startup code uses a connection to the `master` database as it's signal that the container's ready, however, there's clearly a significant gap between the initialisation of the system database(s) and user databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the key to this problem was how the test code was checking the readiness of the SQL Server instance in the container.

The code tries to create a connection to the SQL Server instance running in the container using the `master` database. What I didn't know, was that while the `master` database might be ready and accepting connections, other databases might not be. I changed the code to try and connect using the actual database that the test wants to use, rather than `master` and this appears to work.

The local tests must've been passing locally because the container was able to complete initialisation consistently quicker in that environment compared with the Azure DevOps environment.